# ASP.NET Web API 2 Setting Controller Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have been scratching my head for a whole day since I cannot figure out what is wrong in my code.

First, I have a working controller as this one:

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers {
    [RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
    public class AccountController : ApiController {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("Register")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(AccountModel model) {
            ...
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I add a new controller and introduce a new route, problem arises.

The new controller is as follows:

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers {
    [RoutePrefix("api/Admin")]
    public class AdminController : ApiController {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("Encrypt")]
        public IHttpActionResult Encrypt(string clientSecret) {
            ...
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I make the request via [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) like this:

[image: Postman Request]

Unfortunately, an error is returned:

```
{
    "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/api/admin/encrypt'."
}
```

I am using the default route mapping configuration defined in `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Can anyone shed some light on it?

---

## UPDATE

If I send the POST request in this way, I can get the `Ok()` response successfully.

[image]

I have a question now. **Why can I only pass the parameter via the URL but not with a form object?**

Comment: Why are you POSTing rather than GETting?

Comment: I want to encrypt my data and store it in DB, then afterwards send me back the result. "api/account/register" is a working POST request too.

Comment: can you try this route [Route("Encrypt/{clientSecret}")] and check whether it is working or not

Comment: It turns out to be a [Parameter Binding](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) issue. However, I still failed to use x-www-form as a data container for my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call with the parameter, include parameter in route attribute and add POST verb as follows:

```
  [Route("Encrypt/{clientSecret}")]
  [HttpPost]
  public IHttpActionResult Encrypt(string clientSecret) {
            ...
            return Ok();
       }
```

Then call as follows:

```
 http://localhost/api/admin/encrypt/123456
```

However convention for post methods is without the parameter as follows:

```
[Route("Encrypt")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Encrypt() {
            ...
            return Ok();
       }
   }
```

Then call as follows:

```
 http://localhost/api/admin/encrypt
```

If you do not want to add the POST verb, you can prefix the methods with the POST verb as follows:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostEncrypt(string clientSecret)

public IHttpActionResult PostEncrypt()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the slight change in your route definition:
api/{controller}/{action}/{id} 
The reason, imo, is that Web api actions default to the standard accept verbs.
Then you can name your api action methods anyhow, only decorate them with the relevant accept attribute.

Comment: Why does the route `api/account/register` works then? I have been using the same route definition `api/{controller}/{id}` from the start.

Comment: Do you happen to call register through get? That's actions default value

Comment: Both the working and non-working requests are `POST`.

Comment: I remember this wierd behavior in Web Api when passing string parameters via the post verb, it did not work for me until I prefixed the request body with "=" symbol. For Instance in your case you will have body:  =123456 Note you do not specify the parameter name

Comment: Did you try the = prefix? How did it go.

Comment: Have been busy. Gonna try it out tonight or tomorrow. Thanks.